# Significance of output of netstat -i command in AIX

Tags: shell-script, networking, network-interface, aix, netstat

The output of the `netstat-i` command on AIX 7.1 / AIX 7.2 :

```
Name  Mtu   Network     Address            Ipkts Ierrs    Opkts Oerrs  Coll
en0   65390 link#2      e2.f9.3a.a8.fc.2     1205     0       71     0     0
en0   65390 10.140.128  nix-aix71-vs02-v     1205     0       71     0     0
lo0   16896 link#1                            108     0      108     0     0
lo0   16896 127         localhost             108     0      108     0     0
lo0   16896 localhost                         108     0      108     0     0
```

- Why there are duplicates of the interfaces in the output.? What is the significance of the them?
- For ex: Why there are two `en0` with different Network and different Address.?
- Would the value for Ipkts, Ierrs, Opkts, Oerrs and Coll will always be same if the interface Name is same?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember this is auto-generated name of network if you do not name explicitly this network. You can check in file `/usr/samples/tcpip/networks` for sample file about network naming in AIX.

Here is extract from [AIX documentation (7.1)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/networks_TCPIP.htm):
Description

> The /etc/networks file contains information about the known networks
>   that comprise the DARPA Internet. Each network is represented by a
>   single line in the networks file. The format for the entries in the
>   networks file is:
>
> Name Number Aliases
>
> The fields are described as follows: Item     Description Name    Specifies
>   an official network name. Number  Specifies a network number. Aliases
>     Specifies any unofficial names used for the network.
>
> Items on a line are separated by one or more spaces or tab characters.
>   Comments begin with a # (pound sign). Routines that search the
>   networks file do not interpret characters from the beginning of a
>   comment to the end of that line. Network numbers are specified in
>   dotted-decimal notation. A network name can contain any printable
>   character except a field delimiter, new-line character, or comment
>   character.
>
> The networks file is normally created from the official network
>   database maintained at the Network Information Center (NIC). The file
>   can be modified locally to include unofficial aliases or unknown
>   networks.This file is part of TCP/IP in Network Support Facilities.

Edit: So they are the same interface, the same route, the same network

1

```
en0   65390 link#2      e2.f9.3a.a8.fc.2     1205     0       71     0     0
```

and 2

```
en0   65390 10.140.128  nix-aix71-vs02-v     1205     0       71     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks Romeo for the answer, But I am still a beginner at Network and Interfaces, so I couldn't summarise anything from your reply. Can you tell if this is correct inference :

 1) One `en0` is the alias of the other. 
 2) Both the `en0` gives same output for Ipkts, Opkts,etc.

Comment: @JayJoshi, What mean is 1st line is with resolve the network name, 2nd w/o resolve the network name. So they are the same interface, the same route, the same network

Comment: Actually they are technically not the same, one is the regular IPv4 address you are probably using, and the other is the automatically generated link-local IPv6 address.